# git log -Sstr give commit without str in its diff

Tags: git

I search in repo for commits that change some string count with command:

```
git log -Sstr -- some/file.name
```

Then I look at that commits diffs with:

```
git show commit-id
```

Diffs shown contain lines added and removed. But for one of commits searching for "str"
over its diff gives no result, meaning that diff contains no "str". Search is done interactively in default pager of OS: less on ubuntu 18.04.
In that commit files only added and modified not deleted.

Question is: how it is possible?

git version 2.17.1

Comment: I feel like you might be best to give a concrete example that others can test against.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart i can't, it is private repo(

Comment: Can you share the `str` ? Does it contains special characters ?

Comment: @LeGEC str = Stiffener, just simple parameter name

Answer (score 1):

Try running :

```
git log -Sstr -p -- file
```

The `-p` option should display the diff which triggers the `-S` filtering option.

Comment: Thank you for -p option, it helped to find the answer

Answer (score 0):

After investigating with `-p` option advised by LeGEC I found what's happening.
My actual command line for search in log is:

```
git log --follow -Sstr -- some/file.js
```

Trying with `-p` option and searching for 'str' gave me right result: 'str' is present in commit diff in deleted line. Diff is done between new renamed file and old not renamed which contained 'str'.

But if I try to use

```
git show commit-id
```

diff is done between new renamed file and `/dev/null` so deletion of 'str' not in diff